# Is there a reason why some of my nav items are underlined when active, and others are not?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on moving some nav items around on an exiting site but am unfamiliar with php (though I assumed this would just me a css issue). The issue is that some of the nav items are underlined correctly when clicked (active) while other are not.

I've tried working with the code outside of the site but because it is also php I cant get it to render properly in the browser

```
#main_nav .active{
    text-decoration: underline!important;
}
```

```
<nav id="main_nav" class="nav-mobile col-md-8 col-md-pull-4 col-md-float-break">
    <ul>
        <li id="home_link"><a href="/<?php echo $data['lang']['language']; ?>" <?php if ($data['page_info']['disc'] == 'home') echo 'class="active"'; ?> ><?php echo $data['lang']['home_link']; ?></a></li>
        <li id="started_link"><a href="/<?php echo $data['lang']['language']; ?>/get-started" <?php if ($data['page_info']['disc'] == 'get_started') echo 'class="active"'; ?> ><?php echo $data['lang']['started_link']; ?></a></li>
        <li id="new_vehicle_link"><a href="/<?php echo $data['lang']['language']; ?>/lease-or-purchase" <?php if ($data['page_info']['disc'] == 'lease-or-purchase') echo 'class="active"'; ?> ><?php echo $data['lang']['new_vehicle_link']; ?></a></li>
        <li id="keep_vehicle_link"><a href="/<?php echo $data['lang']['language']; ?>/purchase-your-vehicle" <?php if ($data['page_info']['disc'] == 'purchase-your-vehicle') echo 'class="active"'; ?> ><?php echo $data['lang']['keep_vehicle_link']; ?></a></li>
        <li id="vehicle_link"><a href="/<?php echo $data['lang']['language']; ?>/turn-in-your-vehicle" <?php if ($data['page_info']['disc'] == 'turn_in_your_vehicle') echo 'class="active"'; ?> ><?php echo $data['lang']['vehicle_link']; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Which ones aren't rendering properly?

Comment: all but the second and fifth

Answer (score 0):

It's because you switch from dashes to underscores.

get-started -> get_started

turn-in-your-vechicle -> turn_in_your_vehicle

These will never match, so they will never be `active`